# design decision behind buttons

Tags: buttons, design-patterns, design

What is the design decision behind the buttons 'Open in app' and 'get started'?

In the image below we see two buttons or clickable links one has a boundary and another does not. But what thought process goes even behind this small thing? Does it mean we are assuming that 'Get started' is more important than the other option hence giving it a boundary will make users it more noticeable I am just guessing but I am looking for insights.

[image]

Comment: You might want to edit your question towards a specific UX problem you are dealing with; I've answered your question, but this alone is fairly speculative. Are you encountering situations where you need to decide on what to emphasize?

Answer (score 1):

#### You probably won't know unless you ask the design team, but there are some principles for hierarchy and salience.

Without having access to the decision making process, this is speculative.

However, there are some popular guidelines in use for determining the perceived importance of a UI element.

**Google Material as an example**

Buttons take on 3 levels of salience:

[image]

> 1. Text button (low emphasis)
>    Text buttons are typically used for less important actions.

> 2. Outlined Button (medium emphasis)
>    Outlined buttons are used for more emphasis than text buttons due to the stroke.

> 3. Contained button (high emphasis)
>    Contained buttons have more emphasis, as they use a color fill and shadow.

> 4. Toggle button
>    Toggle buttons group a set of actions using layout and spacing. They’re used less often than other button types.

Generally, when you get to Contained buttons, these are the primary action on the screen, ideally *the one thing* that's most important to do.

As this applies to you directly, you as a designer need to weigh the actions in the application, their context in a view, and what outcomes are important to the user (and your business model). That can assist in choosing the proper form factor to achieve the outcomes you need.

Answer (score 0):

An outlined button next to a text button gives the user a kind of hierarchy of potential actions. As designers we illicitly push the user to chose to click the first one (outlined button). Note that it (outlined button) is put on the right side, so if it is in a touch screen it will be the easiest button to reach (in Thumb friendly navigation zone).